# Stop "iPhone is not Activated" message from appearing

Tags: ios

I bought a used iPhone 5s not to use as a phone, but to use like an iPod touch. I bought a cheap, dummy SIM card to get it activated. All is well, but I keep getting the`iPhone is Not Activated. Contact Your Carrier.` message.

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: The actual message is "Iphone is not Activated"  Contact your carrier . . . . the only way to get rid of it is to hit "dismiss" but it keeps coming back.

Comment: it's not 'your phone' until it's activated. Have you tried it when connected to wifi, or can't you get that far?

Comment: wifi is great!  Have gotten new apps just fine.  It's just the annoying message that keeps popping up   I don't want to use it as a phone at all.  Appreciate your help!

Comment: Take the SIM out.

Answer (score -2):

Turn off iMessage and FaceTime

Comment: Please provide more detail than that answer.  Explain why you think that answer will solve the question.  Provide links to sites that back-up your answer.  See [answer] for how to provide a good answer.